# Query the created date of a custom field?

Tags: soql, tooling-api

I'm trying to do a large scale field cleanup within my org, and I'm looking to get a list of the custom fields by object (in this case the Account sobject), some basic details for those fields, and most importantly the created date of those fields.  I cannot figure out how to get the created date though - which seems very odd.

Within the developer console, I'm using the Query Editor tab, and I'm entering in the following query:

```
SELECT QualifiedApiName, LastModifiedDate, DeveloperName, (Select DataType From Particles)
FROM FieldDefinition
WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName ='Account'
```

I should note that I have the "Use Tooling API" checkbox enabled.  If I enter in the CreatedDate attribute I get the following error back:

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:44
>   No such column 'CreatedDate' on entity 'FieldDefinition'.

Can someone please point me in the right direction here?  Seems very odd that I can't pull in the CreatedDate of a custom field, so I believe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Your query does not include the `CreatedDate` field...

Comment: @AdrianLarson i did a describe call on FieldDefinition. there is no field  named as CreatedDate

Comment: The [CustomField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm) Metadata API entity doesn't have a CreatedDate field either.

Comment: There is only 'LastModifiedDate' not CreatedDate ..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The FieldDefinition table doesn't have a CreatedDate field, but CustomField does (but it's not in the documentation). It seems to me that you'll need to perform two queries and then match up the records by DeveloperName:

```
SELECT NameSpacePrefix, DeveloperName, TableEnumOrId, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate FROM CustomField WHERE TableEnumOrId = 'Account'
```

Plus your original query. Note that DeveloperName won't include the `__c`, so you'll need to check the results from FieldDefinition to determine if it should be a custom field or not.

Comment: To add its available only via Toolin API, and The field Namespace is actually "NamespacePrefix" .

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Yeah, I thought that looked weird.

Comment: @sfdcfox amazing - this gave me exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: For Custom object, we can take the ID of object from the URL.  

Ex : SELECT NameSpacePrefix,DeveloperName, TableEnumOrId, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate FROM CustomField WHERE TableEnumOrId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' order by createddate desc

In where condition just mention you object 15 digit ID that you can copy from the object field URL

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox helped a lot!!